# Screen Coordinates to 2D World

Tags: vb.net, opengl, math

This more of a mathy nature but anyway. I need to be able to detect where I click in an image displayed in a quad in OpenGl. The quad is 5000x5000 in size and is rendered at 0,0. Now from what I have seen this is rendered from the middle of the window. This renders the quad in the bottom left corner of the axis's. To counter this, rather than change the vertex's of the quad, and since I need to pan as well I transform before I draw the quad.

So to make the quad centered at startup, I pan by GL.Translate(-2500, -2500), 0).

Now the mouse coordinates are relative to the top left corner of the window, so I break them into a fraction e.g. Mouse.X / Width Mouse.Y / Height

This is where it gets iffy. I know I need to multiply by 5000 but I also need to incorporate the pan somehow.

Im not sure if this is important but this is how my Ortho matrix is setup:

```
GL.Ortho(-G_.MapSize * 1.5 ^ ZoomFactor, G_.MapSize * 1.5 ^ ZoomFactor, G_.MapSize * 1.5 ^ ZoomFactor, -G_.MapSize * 1.5 ^ ZoomFactor, -1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GL has clear conecpets of object space, clip space, normalized device coords and window space. Your usage of `glOrtho()` and `glTranslate()` implies that you use the old fixed function, where also the eye-space is well-defined.

When you want to map window sapce points (like mouse coords) back into object space, you need to invert the calculations the gl does. The transformation pipeline for vertices is the following:

1. multiply modelview matrix MV by object space vertex position to get eye space coords (only in fixed-function GL, in the programmable pipeline, this step is completely user-defined)
2. multiply projection matrix P by eye space position to get clip-space position (only in fixed-function GL, in the programmable pipeline, this step is completely user-defined)
3. divide by by clip space w component to get cartesian normalized device coords. In this space, the viewing volume is an axis-aligne cube in the range [-1,1] along each axis. whit z=-1 reprensenting the near plane and z=1 the far plane
4. transform the NDCs to window space by taking the viewport into accout. the point (-1,1) is to be mapped to the (bottom left corner of the) bottom-left pixel of the viewport, (1,1) is mapped to the (top-right corner of the) top-right pixel of the viewport. Z is transformed from [-1,1] to [0,1] and might be further transfrom by the specified `glDepthRange`, and later might by converted to some integer representation.

If you have a given 2D mouse position, you can simply invert that scheme:

1. Find the viewport coords (which is trivial if you use the full window, just be aware that GL uses the origin at bottom-left, while most window systems put the origin at top-left corner).
2. Undo the viewport transform to put x and y in the range of [-1,-1].
3. Now you can directly use these as clip space coords by assuimg w=1. In the general case, each 2d mouse position represents a ray, so you can use *two* points to project the ray back, like z=-1 and z=1. However, in your orthogonal projection case, one point is enough. So multiply the inverse Projection P^-1 by the clip space coords of your point(s).
4. You now have the eye space position. Multiply the inverse modelview matrix MV^-1 by the eye space coords to get back to object space.(In the general case, you should be aware that you have to divide the final result by the w component, since you were in a projective space. With orthogonal projection, and only affine transformations in ModelView, w will be 1 so you can ignore it).

**EDIT**

Since that operation is common, there are also some utility functions implementing this. As you are using the matrix stack of the GL, the easiest solution is just to use [`gluUnproject()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluUnProject.xml) from the GLu library. All you need are the 3D window coords of the point, and the matrices adn viewport setting which where used when you did draw the object, which can be queried using `glGetDoublev()` using the various `glGet` functions. There is a [full example at the old NeHe site](http://nehe.gamedev.net/article/using_gluunproject/16013/).

With modern GL, you have to do this all by yourself. However, the popular GLM library also has a [`glm::unProject`](http://glm.g-truc.net/api/a00151.html#ga540d5f6bb3f41e5dfa38d6ebd8771765) method similiar to the GLU one.

Comment: This is obviously the correct answer, but way way out my league, as such I'm marking it as the answer and hope it helps someone else. I'm just going to find a different way to do what I want entirely because I'm an absolute novice at OpenGL.

Comment: @TheEmpireStrikesBack: actually, that answer is less about the GL than it is about maths. I updated my answer to cover the more practical aspects.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using OpenTK so I don thave unProject, but I googled it and found a function for it, then I found this http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/51820/c-opentk-converting-screen-coords-to-world-coords Which is the function and how to use, I'm going to add an answer with my code on how it works.  It works really well now, quite happy with it.

Comment: I've noticed a bit of a problem, I have my viewport set up with an aspect ratio nothing complex just: `OnResize glViewPort(0,0, 950 * (width / height), 950 * (width / height))` When I resize the window the unproject breaks on the Y axis. The X stays perfectly on spot but the Y will go up. So if I click somewhere the actual point will be much higher in the map than where I clicked. E.g. I clicked (100,5000) the point will come out at (100, 2647) Its different every time I change the window size so I can't just offset it.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an extension on my comments, this is the working code for unProjecting mouse coordinates to world coordinates. Its pretty much a practical example of what derhass said. 
Calling the function:

```
    Dim modelViewMatrix As Matrix4
    Dim projectionMatrix As Matrix4
    Dim viewport(4) As Integer
    GL.GetFloat(GetPName.ModelviewMatrix, modelViewMatrix)
    GL.GetFloat(GetPName.ProjectionMatrix, projectionMatrix)
    GL.GetInteger(GetPName.Viewport, viewport)
    Dim cords As Vector4 = GF.UnProject(projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix, New Size(viewport(2), viewport(3)), New Vector2(e.Position.X, e.Position.Y))
```

The function:

```
    Public Function UnProject(ByRef projection As Matrix4, ByVal view As Matrix4, ByVal viewport As Size, ByVal mouse As Vector2) As Vector4
        Dim vec As Vector4

        vec.X = 2.0F * mouse.X / CSng(viewport.Width) - 1
        vec.Y = -(2.0F * mouse.Y / CSng(viewport.Height) - 1)
        vec.Z = 0
        vec.W = 1.0F

        Dim viewInv As Matrix4 = Matrix4.Invert(view)
        Dim projInv As Matrix4 = Matrix4.Invert(projection)

        Vector4.Transform(vec, projInv, vec)
        Vector4.Transform(vec, viewInv, vec)

        If vec.W > Single.Epsilon OrElse vec.W < Single.Epsilon Then
            vec.X /= vec.W
            vec.Y /= vec.W
            vec.Z /= vec.W
        End If

        Return vec
    End Function
```