# 3D Scene transformations not quite working

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, projection, glm-math

In an attempt to convert screen space coordinates into world space coordinates, I've been doing the following calculation:

WorldSpace Vector  = inverse(Projection Matrix) * inverse(View Matrix) * ScreenSpace vector

Up to this point, I believe I have most of my calculations right, however I'm unsure of how to perform the last step needed in order to have my vector transformed to world coordinates.

**Problem:**

- I've been told that the last step of this process is to divide my results by the variable "w" because we are using homogeneous coordinates. However I have no idea what "w" represents.

I've defined the following variables (x and y are integers of the mouse coordinates):

```
GLint viewport[4];
GLfloat winX, winY;
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

winX = ((float)x/viewport[2]*2)-1;
winY = ((float)(viewport[3]-y)/viewport[3]*2)-1;

glm::mat4x4 mMatrix;
glm::mat4x4 vMatrix;

glm::mat4x4 cameraTransformation;
```

And I performed the following transformations:

```
cameraTransformation = glm::rotate(cameraTransformation, (float)alpha*(float)M_PI/180, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
cameraTransformation = glm::rotate(cameraTransformation, (float)beta*(float)M_PI/180, glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));

glm::vec4 cameraPosition = (cameraTransformation * glm::vec4(camX, camY, distance, 0));
glm::vec4 cameraUpDirection = cameraTransformation * glm::vec4(0, 1, 0, 0);

vMatrix = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(cameraPosition[0],cameraPosition[1],cameraPosition[2]), glm::vec3((float)camX, (float)camY, 0.0), glm::vec3(cameraUpDirection[0],cameraUpDirection[1],cameraUpDirection[2]));

glm::mat4x4 mat =  glm::inverse(vMatrix) * glm::inverse(mMatrix) * glm::inverse(pMatrix);
glm::vec4 wSC = (mat) * glm::vec4(winX,winY,0,0);
```

In my resize event, my pMatrix is projected as such:

```
pMatrix = glm::mat4x4(1.0);//sets identity
pMatrix = glm::perspective( (float)fov*(float)M_PI/180, (float) width / (float) height, (float)0.001, (float)10000 );
```

Note: I've had issues in the past with using the GLU library, and apparently with using unProject functions overall, so I've elected to perform the calculations myself. At this point its almost a justification of effort, but I'm not going to use preexisting unprojection functions period.

Comment: You forgot to invert the viewport transform. You also forgot to divide the final result by `w`.

Comment: Where do you mean for the viewport transform? The y axis is inverted, and is only used in "winY", or am I missing something? And what do you mean by "w", the viewport width?

Comment: The projection matrix does _not_ transform into window space, but into clip space. Then, the perspective divide is applied, and we reach NDC space, where the viewing volumne is [-1,1] in all dimensions. Finally, the viewport transform is applied to pixel space. So you need to convert your position to [-1,1] NDC space first, before you can apply the inverse projection. With `w` I do mean the `w` coordinate of the 4d homogeneous vectors.

Comment: Also note that glm already provides an [unproject method](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.2/api/a00245.html#gac38d611231b15799a0c06c54ff1ede43) which can take your view and projection matrix as well as the viewport and do all the internal math for you.

Comment: Okay, I'm completely confused now. My whole aim is for ray drawing, that's why I'm trying to convert from screen space to world space. I tried unprojecting the screen coordinates, and my values were only in the range of -.005 to +.005. Could you explain what changes to my procedure I need to make?

Comment: Why don't you use glm's unproject. I've just seen that your matrix multiplication order is also wrong.

Comment: I said that I did try it. I've done it just as you said, and my range is wrong. I'm not turning down any help, I really do want this to work, and I'm trying to understand how to get it to work. I've been told to take the math into my own hands, so I'd rather do the multiplications myself. What is the right order than? Point out the problems, I want to know! Don't be afraid to criticize

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20440798/screen-coordinates-to-2d-world/20444101#20444101) is of any help to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70929/discussion-between-yattabyte-and-derhass).

Comment: Okay, I have everything else set up correctly I think, I just don't know what the homogeneous coordinates are that I'm supposed to divide by - "w".

Answer (score 0):

In this last stage of my ray picking problem, I was informed that I was doing several things wrong:

1. My z coordinate for a window space near plane should be -1, not 0
2. Reminder that I need 2 separate vectors at the opposing planes, don't just use 1 for testing, run it through the actual ray picker to see if it works.
3. Use a "w" value of 1, not 0. This is the last spot of the `glm::vec4 wSC = (mat) * glm::vec4(winX,winY,0,0);` line.
4. That I need to convert my mouse coordinates into NDC coordinates before performing any calculations, so this is:

- divide mouse x by screen width, times 2, minus 1.
- subtract mouse y **from** screen height, divide by screen height, times 2, minus 1: `winX = ((float)x/viewport[2]*2)-1; winY = ((float)(viewport[3]-y)/viewport[3]*2)-1;`

Since my problem extended over quite a great length of time, and took up several questions, I owe credit to a few individuals who helped me along the way:

- [srobins of facepunch](http://facepunch.com/member.php?u=674814), in [this thread](http://facepunch.com/showthread.php?t=1450824)
- [derhass from here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2327517/derhass), in this question, and this [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70929/discussion-between-yattabyte-and-derhass)